# React js problema con array de objetos

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, react-axios

Estoy haciendo una pagina con la api de poke api, el problema principal que tengo es con los array que tienen un objeto dentro, lo que hago es pasarlos a un state que sea un array vacio para poder recorrelos con un map, el problema es que esto me hace la pagina muy pesada y me tarda mucho en cargar, me podrian dar alguna sugerencia?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: debes subir tu codigo para poder ver que haces mal, intenta no usar timeouts, reducir la cantidad de pokemones en pantalla, usar paginador, buscador, intentar no recorrer una y otra vez por cada registro. optimizar tu codigo o tenerlo pre procesado con un backend y una base de datos

Comment: No sé bien como editar ponerlo arriba, de todas formas ya lo subí en respuesta

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import { handleColor } from "./helpers/type";

export const PokemonCard = ({ pokemon }) => {
  const [obtenerPokemon, setObtenerPokemon] = useState([]);
  const [obtenerSprite, setObtenerSprite] = useState([]);
  const [obtenerTipo, setObtenerTipo] = useState([]);
  const [shiny, setShiny] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const request = await Axios.get(pokemon);
        setObtenerPokemon(request.data);
        setObtenerSprite(request.data.sprites);
        setObtenerTipo(request.data.types);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  console.log(obtenerPokemon.name);
  return (
    <>
      <div className="card__pokemon container">
        {shiny ? (
          <img
            src={obtenerSprite.front_shiny}
            className="card__img"
            alt={obtenerPokemon.name}
          />
        ) : (
          <img
            src={obtenerSprite.front_default}
            className="card__img"
            alt={obtenerPokemon.name}
          />
        )}
        <button
          className="btn btn-primary mt-2"
          onClick={() => {
            setShiny(!shiny);
          }}
        >
          Shiny
        </button>

        <p className="card__pokemon-name">{obtenerPokemon.name}</p>
        <div className="card__types">
          {obtenerTipo.map((item) => (
            <p
              key={item.type.name}
              style={{ background: handleColor(item.type.name) }}
              className="card__type-item"
            >
              {item.type.name}
            </p>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: cuanto tarda en responder la API y cuanto tarda en generarse los bloques? podria ser que la lentitud de la pagina sea culpa de la API y no de los array, es muy dificil que esa sea la razon

Comment: cuando bajo el limite de 20 a 10 se generan más rápido, pero no hay problema entonces que para mostrar esos 10 cada uno aparezca en consola 6 veces como en la imagen?

Comment: ya, tu problema es el siguiente:

cada vez que generas un PokemonCard, haces un
const request = await Axios.get(pokemon);

esto congela tu codigo, y espera hasta que el axios responda.
lo que debes hacer es usar un await Promise.All([Axios.get(pokemon_1),Axios.get(pokemon_2)...])
 y asi te traes todos los pokemones de una sola vez, y luego generas las cartas. asi estaras haciendo los llamados de forma paralela y luego esas respuestas enviarselas a las cards, eso deberia agilizar un monton tu sistema